# Is it a good practice to use "binary" as an encoding for reading files if I don't care about human readability?

Tags: node.js, parsing, dbf, dbase

The scenario is that I want to parse dbf files in my program(nodejs). When I choose utf-8 as an encoding, some of the field sizes are read incorrectly which results in incorrect data representation.(Field sizes are read during the parsing of the header). Note that I want to parse the files to import them to SQL and I have no interest in viewing the data. Is it an efficient practice in general if I don't want to represent the data?

Comment: DBF file headers are binary, and should be treated as binary. They're not strings. UTF-8 is an invalid encoding for binary data.

Comment: @ken: looks like an answer to me.